# why a captured image bitmap from Android camera is rotated

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I am using IMAGE_CAPTURE camera intent to capture and image and storing it in a file using MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT. When I receive the image in onActivityResult, the bitmap is rotated.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this please.

Intent and passing the uri where I want the file to be stored

```
private fun capturePhoto() {
    val capturedImage = File(this.requireContext().externalCacheDir, "utility_bill.jpg")
    if (capturedImage.exists()) {
        capturedImage.delete()
    }
    capturedImage.createNewFile()
    mUri = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
        FileProvider.getUriForFile(
            this.requireContext(),
            this.requireContext().applicationContext.packageName,
            capturedImage
        )
    } else {
        Uri.fromFile(capturedImage)
    }

    val intent = Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE")
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mUri)
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE)
}
```

in onActivityResult bitmap is rotated.

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        hideScreen.visibility = View.GONE
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE) {
            uploadedImageCount++
            val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(
                this.requireContext().contentResolver.openInputStream(mUri!!)
            )
}}
```

Image that I captured
[image]

when I debugged the bitmap received in the code, it is rotataed

[image]

Any suggestions on how I can resolve this please

Thanks in advance
R

Comment: @blackapps thanks I will correct my question

Answer (score 0):

I Faced The Same issue when i was developing the app most this was the case for devices like Samsung, HTC and some devices....This Happens because of Exif Interface which is different for the devices mentioned Above so make a separate Java class **ExifUtil.java** and the code goes like this
**Note This Code Is In Java**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.os.Build;

public class ExifUtil {
    /**
//     * @see https://sylvana.net/jpegcrop/exif_orientation.html
     */
    public static Bitmap rotateBitmap(String src, Bitmap bitmap) {
        try {
            int orientation = getExifOrientation(src);

            if (orientation == 1) {
                return bitmap;
            }

            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            switch (orientation) {
                case 2:
                    matrix.setScale(-1, 1);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    matrix.setRotate(180);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    matrix.setRotate(180);
                    matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    matrix.setRotate(90);
                    matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    matrix.setRotate(90);
                    break;
                case 7:
                    matrix.setRotate(-90);
                    matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
                    break;
                case 8:
                    matrix.setRotate(-90);
                    break;
                default:
                    return bitmap;
            }

            try {
                Bitmap oriented = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
                bitmap.recycle();
                return oriented;
            } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return bitmap;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return bitmap;
    }

    private static int getExifOrientation(String src) throws IOException {
        int orientation = 1;

        try {
            /**
             * if your are targeting only api level >= 5
             * ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(src);
             * orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 1);
             */
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 5) {
                Class<?> exifClass = Class.forName("android.media.ExifInterface");
                Constructor<?> exifConstructor = exifClass.getConstructor(new Class[] { String.class });
                Object exifInstance = exifConstructor.newInstance(new Object[] { src });
                Method getAttributeInt = exifClass.getMethod("getAttributeInt", new Class[] { String.class, int.class });
                Field tagOrientationField = exifClass.getField("TAG_ORIENTATION");
                String tagOrientation = (String) tagOrientationField.get(null);
                orientation = (Integer) getAttributeInt.invoke(exifInstance, new Object[] { tagOrientation, 1});
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return orientation;
    }
}
```

and OnActivityResult where save it like this
Bitmap orientedBitmap = ExifUtil.rotateBitmap(img_path, myBitmap);

```
this will automatically determine the orientation of the mage and rotate it to Potrait...!!
```

Comment: thank you I will try this

Comment: by any chance do you have equivalent Kotlin code for this please?

Comment: `This Happens because of Exif Interface which is different for the devices mentioned ` No not the exif is different but the image is saved rotated and the orientation tags tells you that it is rotated. There is nothing wrong in doing so.

Comment: @blackapps the above solution is the correct solution?. do you suggest something else?

Comment: Probably it works. But it is pretty complicated with those classes and function calls using class names and function names. Much simpler exif orientaion code has been posted a hundred times. Google for it and then translate to kotlin if you need kotlin.

Comment: Oh.. sorry!! The simple code is in the comment above it! Two lines only.

Comment: what you mean is get exif orientation using ` * ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(src);
             * orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 1);` and have the code in rotateBitmap function

Comment: is the above right what you are referring to @blackapps